# Live agent dismisslabel usage

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, liveagent, servicecloud

I want to use a URL which redirect customer when support agent was not available on chat. I have used dimiss label to close the chat.

Is there any way to redirect customer through URL or can we embed VF page in Custom chat page.

Any answer or guidance will be really appreciated.[image]